# Floating Icon with Navigation Drawer Animation is not hiding while drawer is open

Tags: android

I am using Floating icon and `NavigationDrawer` but when I open Drawer my animation of floating icon is not close they are remain open and when I used `alpha 1-slideOffset`, icons are hiding but working on click what should I do to completely close animation while drawer is open?

I am also working with different `SDK` devices. Is it possible to use same code for all devices?

This is what I've tried:

```
 private void initUi() {

    fab_1 = (FloatingMenuButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_1);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        fab_1.setStartAngle(0)
                .setEndAngle(360)
                .setRadius(150)
                .setAnimationType(AnimationType.EXPAND)
                .setMovementStyle(MovementStyle.FREE);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        fab_1.setStartAngle(0)
                .setEndAngle(360)
                .setRadius(150)
                .setAnimationType(AnimationType.EXPAND)
                .setMovementStyle(MovementStyle.FREE);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        fab_1.setStartAngle(0)
                .setEndAngle(360)
                .setRadius(150)
                .setAnimationType(AnimationType.EXPAND)
                .setMovementStyle(MovementStyle.FREE);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        fab_1.setStartAngle(0)
                .setEndAngle(360)
                .setRadius(150)
                .setAnimationType(AnimationType.EXPAND)
                .setMovementStyle(MovementStyle.FREE);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        fab_1.setStartAngle(0)
                .setEndAngle(360)
                .setRadius(160)
                .setAnimationType(AnimationType.EXPAND)
                .setMovementStyle(MovementStyle.FREE);
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        fab_1.setStartAngle(0)
                .setEndAngle(360)
                .setRadius(200)
                .setAnimationType(AnimationType.EXPAND)
                .setMovementStyle(MovementStyle.FREE);
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        fab_1.setStartAngle(0)
                .setEndAngle(360)
                .setRadius(200)
                .setAnimationType(AnimationType.EXPAND)
                .setMovementStyle(MovementStyle.FREE);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        fab_1.setStartAngle(0)
                .setEndAngle(360)
                .setRadius(350)
                .setAnimationType(AnimationType.EXPAND)
                .setMovementStyle(MovementStyle.FREE);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        fab_1.setStartAngle(0)
                .setEndAngle(360)
                .setRadius(500)
                .setAnimationType(AnimationType.EXPAND)
                .setMovementStyle(MovementStyle.FREE);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        fab_1.setStartAngle(0)
                .setEndAngle(360)
                .setRadius(250)
                .setAnimationType(AnimationType.EXPAND)
                .setMovementStyle(MovementStyle.FREE);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
        fab_1.setStartAngle(0)
                .setEndAngle(360)
                .setRadius(150)
                .setAnimationType(AnimationType.EXPAND)
                .setMovementStyle(MovementStyle.FREE);
    }


    fab_1.getAnimationHandler()
            .setOpeningAnimationDuration(500)
            .setClosingAnimationDuration(200)
            .setLagBetweenItems(0)




            .setOpeningInterpolator(new FastOutSlowInInterpolator())

            .setClosingInterpolator(new FastOutLinearInInterpolator())
            .shouldFade(false)
            .shouldScale(true)

            .shouldRotate(false);


    Poultry= (FloatingSubButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_1_sub_fab_left_1);
    Poultry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FloatingActivity.this, PoultryActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });




    //Navigation Drawer


dl = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
t = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dl, R.string.Open,
        R.string.Close){

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            // Visible/Enable the FAB

        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // Hide/Disable the FAB

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            // invert the slideOffset value

            fab_1.setAlpha((1/255)*slideOffset);


        }
    };


    dl.addDrawerListener(t);
    t.syncState();


getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

nv = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nv);
    nv.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        int id=item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.account){
        Intent intent = (new Intent(FloatingActivity.this, ComplaintSplash.class));
        startActivity(intent);
    }



        switch(id)
        {
            case R.id.account:
                Toast.makeText(FloatingActivity.this, "Complain ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            case R.id.settings:
                Toast.makeText(FloatingActivity.this, "Commissioner Karachi Division",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            case R.id.mycart:
                Toast.makeText(FloatingActivity.this, "About Consumer Rights Council",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            case R.id.PrivacyPolicy:
                Toast.makeText(FloatingActivity.this, "Privacy Policy",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            default:
                return true;
        }
    }
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(t.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
            return true;

         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved when I used this code

ondraweropen...

```
drawerView.setAlpha((1/255)*slideOffset);                fab_1.setAlpha((1/255)*slideOffset);
          dl.setDrawerShadow(fab_1);
```